Aggregate hourly data into daily aggregates for mutlitple .TXT files in R
I have multiple .TXT files in the following format:



V1
V2
V3
V4




00000000000101428920180101000000+0120180101001500+01
0.22500000000000
W
KWH


00000000000101428920180101001500+0120180101003000+01
1.42500000000000
W
KWH



where: V1,V3,V4 = character & V2 = numeric
and V1 (timestamp) is composed of:

000000000001014289-> profile number, 18 digits (id=1-18)
20180101000000+01 -> start time of measurement interval (start= 19-32)
20180101001500+01 -> end time of measurement interval (end= 35-48)

The structure of the timestamp is as follows:
E.g. 20140701021500+02
2014 -> YYYY, year// 07 -> MM, month// 01 -> DD, day// 02 -> hh, hour// 15 -> mm, minutes// 00 -> ss, seconds// +02 -> [+-]zz, time zone
My goal is to aggregate the hourly data into daily values for kWh for each ID.
The desired final output should look like this:



id
start_date
kwh




1045289
01.01.14
12.5000


1045289
02.01.14
17.4820



I managed to do this for each file individually, but not for all files at once. In particular, I'm having trouble merging the single .TXT files into one.
In the case of a single .TXT file, I used the following code for the aggregation:
daten <- read.fwf("daten.txt", widths = c(18, 17, 17, 30, 2, 5),
                  col.names = c("ID", "start_date", "end_date", "kWh", "wahr", "unit"))

daten$start_date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(substr(daten$start_date, 1, 14), format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), tz = "UTC")
daten$end_date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(substr(daten$end_date, 1, 14), format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), tz = "UTC")

daten <- daten %>%
  select(ID, start_date, end_date, kWh = kWh, wahr, unit)

data_dailyvalues <- daten %>%
  group_by(ID, start_date = as.Date(start_date)) %>%
  summarize(e_kwh = sum(kWh), .groups = 'drop')

To merge the .TXT files, I used:
data <- list.files(
  pattern = "*.TXT",
  full.names=T) %>%
  lapply(read_delim) %>%
  bind_rows()
)

but I get the following error message:
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..9$0.00000000000000` <double> and `..10$0.00000000000000` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat) 
...

Thank you very much for your help.

How did you get KwH values? V2 I suppose?

Please either (1) provide raw file contents so that we can use your read.fwf(.) command, or better yet (2) since your question is not about FWF, it's about aggregation, skip the read.fwf call and give us dput(head(daten)) in a [code block] so that we can focus on the aggregation itself. Further, (3) If you have a field that is being mis-read as character in some (but not all) files, we need to have that data as well (which may mandate needing the raw text data, not sure).

Did you run rlang::last_trace(), but appears at least one of the .TXT files fails for number or order of columns as indicated by 'can't put character in (now established) numeric column.

@Robin, maybe one file have a coltype problem. Try to read all columns as character first: my_data <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT", full.names = TRUE) %>% map(\(x) read_delim(x, col_types = "cccc")) %>% list_rbind().


Is it read.fwf or read_delim? 2) with read.fwf you can specify colClasses so that all files have the equal columns read with equal classes. And the same with read_delim and col_types.


It looks like read_delim is guessing a different column type for the same column in two of the .txt files -- i.e., it's interpreting the problematic column as a double (numeric) in one file, but as a character in another. It therefore can't bind the column between resulting dataframes since the column types are different.
You can override the (incorrect) guess by explicitly providing the col_types argument in read_delim. Hard to provide the exact code you need without seeing the original data, but that's the general idea...

For what I understand of the problem the following might work.
First of all, break the problem into simpler steps and solve one at a time.

Function read_one_file does precisely that, it reads one file with the appropriate column widths, types and names;
Function parse_date_col is more complicated. It is meant to process the time zone part of the date. In order to do so, it separates the date from the tz component, coerces the date to an actual date object and adds the hours in the tz part;
Function get_start_day calls the previous function and keeps only the date.

Then, I read the files but don't piped the list.files function, I saved its result and pipe that result. Like this I avoid having to repeatedly getting the file names if something goes wrong.
(The same could be made with read_one_file, read them in the lapply loop and only after try the bind and summarise them. Here it follows the question's code.)
read_one_file <- function(file) {
  widths <- c(18, 17, 17, 30, 2, 5)
  # col_names <- c("ID", "start_date", "end_date", "kWh", "wahr", "unit")
  col_types <- readr::cols(ID = "c", start_date = "c", end_date = "c", 
                           kWh = "d", wahr = "c", unit = "c")
  #
  readr::read_fwf(
    file = file,
    col_positions = widths,
    col_types = col_types
  )
}
parse_date_col <- function(x) {
  d <- substr(x, 1L, 14L)
  tz <- substr(x, 15L, 17L)
  lubridate::ymd_hms(d) + lubridate::hours(tz)
}
get_start_day <- function(x) {
  x |> parse_date_col() |> as.Date()
}


txt_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.TXT", full.names = TRUE)
txt_list %>%
  lapply(read_one_file) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(ID, start_day = get_start_day(start_date)) %>%
  summarise(e_kwh = sum(kWh), .groups = 'drop')


Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
However, in the last step (for the "txt_list %>%..." code) I get the following error message: Error in readr::read_fwf(file = file, col_names = col_names, col_positions = widths,  :    unused argument (col_names = col_names)

@RobinBucher OK, you are right, I didn't test it with readr::read_fwf, I only tested it with read_delim. Remove that argument and give it a try to see if the error goes away and if it produces the wanted result.

@RobinBucher Also, Is the pattern in list.files really capitalized, pattern = "*.TXT"?

Since there are nice space delimiters just using normal read.table and subsequent substr should suffice.
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

file_list <- c("file1", "file2")

dat_list <- lapply(file_list, read.table, header=T)

do.call(rbind, 
  lapply(dat_list, \(x) 
    data.frame(id = sub("^0+", "", substr(x$V1, 1, 18)), 
               start_date = ymd(substr(x$V1, 19, 26)),
               kWh = x$V2))) %>% 
  summarize(sum(kWh), .by = c(id, start_date))
       id start_date sum(kWh)
1 1014289 2018-01-01      3.3

Just add elements you need within data.frame
Data
% cat file1
V1  V2  V3  V4
00000000000101428920180101000000+0120180101001500+01    0.22500000000000    W   KWH
00000000000101428920180101001500+0120180101003000+01    1.42500000000000    W   KWH

% cat  file2
V1  V2  V3  V4
00000000000101428920180101000000+0120180101001500+01    0.22500000000000    W   KWH
00000000000101428920180101001500+0120180101003000+01    1.42500000000000    W   KWH

